# R vectorize S3 class constructor

Tags: r, oop, constructor, vectorization

I am creating an S3 class where the constructor has multiple arguments. I would like to pass equal length vectors to the constructor and get back a vector of objects of my new class.

```
myclass <- function(number, letter) {
  this <- list(
    num = number,
    let = letter
  )
  class(this) <- append(class(this), "myclass")
  return(this)
}

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])

c <- myclass(df$a, df$b)
```

But instead of c being a list of 5 objects of type `myclass`, I get a list of 2 objects:

```
> str(c)
List of 2
$ num: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
```

Can I change the constructor function to make this work, or should I use some apply function to call the constructor?

If it is the latter, then I haven't got that to work either - I thought mapply was the solution, but no..

EDIT: Thanks to @rawr comment, I now know that `c <- mapply(myclass, df$a, df$b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` is the correct way to use the `mapply` function here, but we are still faced with the question of whether that belongs inside the constructor or in the code that calls the constructor.

```
> c <- mapply(myclass, df$a, df$b)
> str(c)
List of 10
$ : int 1
$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1
$ : int 2
$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 2
$ : int 3
$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 3
$ : int 4
$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 4
$ : int 5
$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 5
- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 5
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:2] "num" "let"
..$ : NULL
> class(c[[1]])
[1] "integer"
```

I think this explicit loop gives the correct result:

```
c <- list()

for(i in 1:5) {
  c[[i]] <- myclass(df$a[i], df$b[i])
}

> str(c)
List of 5
$ :List of 2
..$ num: int 1
..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
$ :List of 2
..$ num: int 2
..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 2
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
$ :List of 2
..$ num: int 3
..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 3
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
$ :List of 2
..$ num: int 4
..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 4
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
$ :List of 2
..$ num: int 5
..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 5
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
> 
> class(c[[1]])
[1] "list"    "myclass"
```

But I'll repeat what I think is the more important question: 
Can I change the constructor function to make this work, or should I use some apply function (or a loop) to call the constructor?

Comment: use dont use simplify in your mapply? `str(mapply(myclass, df$a, df$b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))`

Comment: Do you want `myclass` to output only a "list" of 2 items of `length == 1` each or is there a chance that you'll need `myclass(df$a, df$b)` as is? If the first, I guess you'll have to add a loop inside `myclass` to "vectorize" it; if the second it might be more convenient to add a loop, like rawr's, afterwards when needed.

Comment: The `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` part definitely fixes the `mapply` function, thank you @rawr for that. This question now becomes one of design philosophy - does that belong inside the constructor, or in the code calling the constructor?

Comment: @alexis_laz I don't understand the distinction you are making - what do you mean by 'as is'?

Comment: @BrianStamper : Are you looking to _how_ to loop inside `myclass` or what might be more suitable? If an output like `myclass(df$a, df$b)` (with `myclass` as, currently, defined in your question) is never desirable, then I guess you'll need to add the loop inside `myclass` to avoid calling a looping function every time you call `myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

You're just not working with the R types correctly. You need to apply the `myclass` function to each element (in this case a row).

```
c1 <- apply(df, 1, function(i) myclass(i[1], i[2]))
str(c1)
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: Named chr "1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
  ..$ let: Named chr "a"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: Named chr "2"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
  ..$ let: Named chr "b"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: Named chr "3"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
  ..$ let: Named chr "c"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: Named chr "4"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
  ..$ let: Named chr "d"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: Named chr "5"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
  ..$ let: Named chr "e"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "list" "myclass"
```

Rather than using a wrapper (`apply`) in the function call as above, you could modify your `myclass` function to do so for you

```
myclass <- function(number, letter) {
  out <- mapply(function(n, l) {
    l1 <- list(num= n, let= l)
    class(l1) <- "myclass"
    return(l1)
  }, n= number, l= letter, SIMPLIFY= FALSE)
  return(out)
} 

str(myclass(df$a, df$b))
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: int 1
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: int 2
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 2
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: int 3
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: int 4
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 4
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ num: int 5
  ..$ let: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 5
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making efforts at reinventing an existing base-R function named `oldClass<-` described on the help page `?inherits`. The "lowest"  class type in R is "logical" so the way to make an atomic vector that can have classes added to it would be with `logical`

```
Vec <- logical(5)
classList <- c("numeric", "character")
Vec2 <- logical(5)
oldClass(Vec) <- classList  # not really a true R _list_
> Vec
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "numeric"   "character"
> inherits(Vec2, "character")
[1] FALSE
> inherits(Vec, "character")
[1] TRUE
```

If you have a list of object names (commonly just called a list) and a modification function, then you can loop over it with sapply or lapply to return a modified list:

```
vList <- list(Vec, Vec2)
vList2 <- lapply( vList, 'oldClass<-', classList)
vList2[[2]]
#----
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "numeric"   "character"
```